# How can I use multiple instances of webkit in c++ gtkmm program?

Tags: c++, gtkmm, webkit2

Short question:

How to make different instances of webkit in C++?

Long question:

I'm writing a simple webbrowser with Webkit2 in C++ on ubuntu with a gtkmm gui.  I would like to use different pages with different Webkit instances.

So far, I have a window to which I can add and remove pages/tabs and Webkit successfully running in the first page/tab.  When I add a second page/tab with an other instance of Webkit I'm not able to load any webpage.  My code in the callback function to add a page/tab:

```
m_WebKit00 = WEBKIT_WEB_VIEW(webkit_web_view_new());    // WebKitWebView* was initialized to the nullptr in the constructor
surf00 = Glib::wrap(GTK_WIDGET(m_WebKit00));            // Gtk::Widget* was initialized to the nullptr in the constructor
m_pViewport00->add(*surf00);                            // Gtk::Viewport* was initialized to the nullptr in the constructor
m_pNotebook->append_page(*m_pViewport00, *m_pTab00);    // Gtk::Notebook* was initialized to the nullptr in the constructor
// same for m_WebKit01, surf01 and so on, ex:
m_WebKit01 = WEBKIT_WEB_VIEW(webkit_web_view_new());
// at start of program one page/tab is created and it is selected; adding/removing pages/tabs works perfectly
```

Code in the on_notebook_switch_page() callback which is run if an other page/tab is selected by the user after adding a page:

```
// here I have a switch to check which page/tab is selected.
// WebKitWebView** m_WebKit(nullptr) // initialized by the constructor
m_WebKit = &m_WebKit00;  // if page 0 is selected   // WebKitWebView** was initialized to the nullptr in the constructor
m_WebKit = &m_WebKit01;  // if page 1 is selected
// and so on;
```

The idea is to let m_WebKit point to the webkit instance of the selected page/tab.

Now I want to load the webpage when someone enters an url in the searchentry with:

```
webkit_web_view_load_uri(m_WebKit, &url[0]);   
// reuse this function whenever the searchentry is used, no matter on what page/tab you are
```

This works perfectly for page 0, but not for page 1.  On page 1 nothing loads, no errors or changes to the page or viewport.

What am I missing here?  Isn't it possible to use multiple instances of webkit?  Would a solution be the use of smart/shared/weak pointers or is the no loading caused by something else?  Any better techniques and/or webkit tutorials?

Please help!!  Thank you

- @273K: edited the code with the same result

Comment: You do not need to store `WebKitWebView** m_WebKit`, `WebKitWebView* m_WebKit` ans `webkit_web_view_load_uri(m_WebKit, &url[0]);`

Comment: @273K: I changed the code like you said, it compiles but with the same result.

Comment: I just can't load the new url from the searchentry into the new page/tab/viewport.